# df_data not defined, unsure of the cause

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, typeerror

working through a tutorial that is supposed to help students do the assignment, but I'm encountering a problem. I'm using python on a notebook project in IBM. Right now the section is simply data exploration. However this error is occurring and I'm not sure how to fix it, no one else seemed to have this problem in this class and the teacher is rather slow to help so I came here!

I tried just defining the variable before its called, but no dice either way.

All the code prior to this is just importing libraries and then parsing the data

```
# Infer the data type of each column and convert the data to the inferred data type
from ingest import *
eu = ExtensionUtils(sqlContext)
df_data_1 = eu.convertTypes(df_data_1)
df_data_1.printSchema()
```

the error I'm getting is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-33250ae79106> in <module>()
      2 from ingest import *
      3 eu = ExtensionUtils(sqlContext)
----> 4 df_data_1 = eu.convertTypes(df_data_1)
      5 df_data_1.printSchema()

/opt/ibm/third-party/libs/python3/ingest/extension_utils.py in convertTypes(self, input_obj, dictVal)
    304          """
    305 
--> 306         checkEnrichType_or_DataFrame("input_obj",input_obj)
    307         self.logger = self._jLogger.getLogger(__name__)
    308         methodname = str(inspect.stack()[0][3])

/opt/ibm/third-party/libs/python3/ingest/extension_utils.py in checkEnrichType_or_DataFrame(param, paramval)
     81     if not isinstance(paramval,(EnrichType ,DataFrame)):
     82         raise TypeError("%s should be a EnrichType class object or DataFrame, got type %s"
---> 83                         % (str(param), type(paramval)))
     84 
     85 

TypeError: input_obj should be a EnrichType class object or DataFrame, got type <class 'NoneType'>
```

Comment: Is what you mention in the title ("df_data is not defined") referring to another error?

Comment: where is df_data_1 defined?  You're giving eu.convertTypes the df_data_1 parameter, but that's not defined anywhere before that line.

Comment: @ewong Thats the thing, it wasn't defined before this yet somehow its supposed to work?? I tried just making it an empty variable (wasn't sure what to put it as otherwise) but then it told me I couldn't do that.

Comment: @AMC Yes thats the error I was referencing

Comment: @MiaP _Yes thats the error I was referencing_ Which is a different error than the one in the post body?

Comment: @AMC You know what it is, sorry about that... I had read a line in the error through my attempts that said that, but perhaps I was wrong...

Comment: @MiaP Which error is the focus of this post, then?

Comment: Now, I'm confused.   The code as you have posted, is missing a definition of 'df_data_1'  which I am assuming is what's being complained about.  Furthermore, upon looking carefully at the convertTypes call(), you're also missing a 'dictVal' parameter.

Comment: @ewong just to clarify, I didn't write the code its prewritten for a tutorial to show how things are done, but then it kept producing these errors, however I figured it out with some trial and error and thorough reading (and rereading) of the material. Turns out its a setting with the notebook that inserts a code snippet before this that needed to be ran. Sorry for wasting your time, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not with the code itself but rather with the notebook. A code snippet from a built in function needed to be inserted first before this.